# Fragment doesn't replace in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm creating a Navigation Drawer like this

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import com.paperwrrk.videos.FragmentVideo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_articles) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_videos) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentVideo())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.fb_posts) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

My FragmentVideo

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.paperwrrk.R;

public class FragmentVideo extends Fragment {
    View myView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
        return myView;
    }
}
```

But when I click on the item from Navigation Drawer second fragment doesn't replace or hide the first one, it  is overlapping like this 
[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi4Oe.png)

Comment: How is the initial fragment being added? I'm going to guess that it's a `<fragment` tag on the xml of the page? If so then what is happening is that the replace command does a `remove` and `add` from the same container, but the fragment you are adding is not in the same container so it remains on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a container instead of using fragment tag

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Now in activity

```
 if(condition)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new FirstFragment()).commit();                    
else
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new SecondFragment()).commit();
```

if this not works try to get the fragment container view ID..Here's the code:

```
transaction.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), fragment);
```

Comment: Getting this error       com.paperwrrk.MainActivity@742d568 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                 at com.paperwrrk.VidFrag.onAttach(VidFrag.java:83)
                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1048)

Comment: in your VidFrag.java delete the onAttach() method...if it is not communicating with the activity

Comment: @KartikShandilya is your overlapping problem solved? if so you can accept the answer..

Answer (score 0):

It works for me...

```
 int id = item.getItemId();
            android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
            if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
                fragment = new ProfileActivity();
                if (fragment != null) {
                    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                }
```